# How to get value of series of textbox in c# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 4-4 textboxes in two column and named them like 
`nfmin1, nfmin2,nfmin3,nfmin4 and nfmax1,nfmax2,nfmax3,nfmax4`

what I want, when I click the submit button 
I get all the values filled in `nfmin1` to `nfmin4` and `nfmax1` to `nfmax4`
using loop

Comment: Please also show some code and what you have tried.

Comment: Controls collection can be accessed by name, it means you can write (for example!) `Enumerable.Range(1, 4).Select(x => Controls[String.Format("nfmin{0}", x)].Text)`. With this enumeration you can do what you want...create an array, build key/value pairs and so on. If you have a specific issue then come back with your code snippet we may try to improve.

Comment: or you can use DataBinding ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can access form controls by name, in this way:

```
void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   List<String> nfminValues = new List<String>();
   List<String> nfmaxValues = new List<String>();
   for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
   {
      TextBox current_nfmin = this.Controls["nfmin" + i.ToString()] as TextBox;
      if (current_nfmin != null)
        nfminValues.Add(current_nfmin.Text);

      TextBox current_nfmax = this.Controls["nfmax" + i.ToString()] as TextBox;
      if (current_nfmax != null)
        nfmaxValues.Add(current_nfmax.Text);
   }
}
```

NOTE: this is just an example I wrote on the fly, I put the content of each `TextBox` in two different lists but you can do anything you want with them.